# laravel lvs and create *blade.php by java service

Tags: laravel

I now have nginx clusters, many php server, I want java services to manage laravel template file, database storage, and then generate php files, stored in the ceph server configuration template path laravel for path ceph service, I tried it, Could not load, but through shared folders or FTP way to work normally

Database management laravel template file, dynamically generated, stored in the resource server ceph

How should I do? Is there any way? If not, the only choice ftp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several packages that allow the storage of Laravel templates in the database.

Here is one:  https://github.com/delatbabel/viewpages